# Buildozer throws "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE"

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I'm pushing my Kivy app into Android phone for testing. Right before pushing I get
this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.gad.kivyandroid signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

What can I do about this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.gad.kivyandroid signatures do not match the previously installed version

This is fairly explicit: the app can't be installed because its signed with a digital signature that doesn't match the current version. This is a security thing, it means that e.g. you can't write an app that pretends to be Spotify because you can't sign it with their key.

This probably happened because you created a new keyfile, or switched computers to one with an existing but different keyfile or something.

To work around it you probably just want to uninstall the version already on your device.